# I want the data of the same row whose check box is checked. My table row is in for loop

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-templates

I want the data of the same row whose check box I will click. my table row is in for loop
and i want to display total price at end but it displaying all the boxes.
And i have take the value by name in my views but here my form component are in for loop so if data is not there it should not come.

here is my **index.html**:

```
    {% for j in package %}
        <tr class="valid-container">
            <td style="cursor:pointer;">
               <input type="checkbox" name="c1" >&nbsp; {{ j.visa_type }}
            </td>

           <td height="52">
                <select class="custom-select processing_type" name="processing_type" data-id="{{ j.id }}" required>
                    <option value="{{ j.price }}" selected>Normal</option>
                    <option value="{{ j.express_price }}">Express</option>
                </select>
           </td>

          <td height="52">
            <select class="custom-select no_of_person" name="no_of_person" data-id="{{ j.id }}" required>
                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>

         </td>

         <td width="190" height="60">
            <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="travel_date" id="date" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                            </div>
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>{{ j.currency_type }}&nbsp;&nbsp; <output name="result" class="package_price">{{ j.price }}</output>.00</td>

                                </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

and this is my **package.js**:

```
$('.valid-container').ready(function() {

var date = $(this).find('#date').attr('required',true);

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var total = $('select[name=processing_type]').val() * $('select[name=no_of_person]').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.package_price').text();

  });

});
```

Comment: You should not use static `id` in looped html templates, due to `id` not being unique anymore which can/does mess up selectors.

Comment: Hi , where is `package_price` in your code ? Also,where you need to that total in last `td` ?

Comment: ok i will remove it but if you have solution than let me know becouse I am stuck in it since yesterday

Comment: ohh sorry i have to edit question wait

Comment: @swati see i added package_price class at last td in question please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).closest("tr")` to get the closest tr and then simply use `.find()` to get the required values from selects and then use `.text()` to add total value to `package_price` .

***Demo Code***(with dummy values) :

```js
//on change of select or checkbox
$('select ,input[type=checkbox] ').on('change', function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr")//get closest tr
  //if checkbox is checked
  if (selector.find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
  //get select valus
    var prcs_type = selector.find("select[name=processing_type]").val();
    var no_person = selector.find("select[name=no_of_person]").val();
    var total = prcs_type * no_person;
    selector.find(".package_price").text(total)//add value to package_prcie.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="valid-container">
    <td style="cursor:pointer;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1">1
    </td>

    <td height="52">
      <select class="custom-select processing_type" name="processing_type" data-id="1" required>
        <option value="19" selected>Normal</option>
        <option value="20">Express</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td height="52">
      <select class="custom-select no_of_person" name="no_of_person" data-id="1" required>
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>

    </td>

    <td width="190" height="60">
      <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="travel_date" id="date" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
          <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
          <div class="input-group-addon">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>{{ j.currency_type }}&nbsp;&nbsp; <output name="result" class="package_price">{{ j.price }}</output>.00</td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="valid-container">
    <td style="cursor:pointer;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1">2
    </td>

    <td height="52">
      <select class="custom-select processing_type" name="processing_type" data-id="2" required>
        <option value="19" selected>Normal</option>
        <option value="20">Express</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td height="52">
      <select class="custom-select no_of_person" name="no_of_person" data-id="2" required>
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>

    </td>

    <td width="190" height="60">
      <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="travel_date" id="date" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
          <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
          <div class="input-group-addon">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>{{ j.currency_type }}&nbsp;&nbsp; <output name="result" class="package_price">{{ j.price }}</output>.00</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you point out difference ? What do you don't want in above code?

Comment: So, you don't need value should get change when checkbox is clicked ? If yes , just remove `input[type=checkbox]` from selector and if you need don't  want to check  `checked` condition for checkboxes remove `if-statement` as well .